# Java Heap issue

Tags: jenkins, out-of-memory, heap-memory

We are using jenkins application for build and monitoring  purpose.. having 64 bit JVM and 64 bit linux.. we are facing the java heap issue ,we have increased the heap limit to 512 Mb to 6 GB still facing the same issue..
 we found that for a 32 bit machine JVM Max mem is 2 GB only?? pls correct me if im wrong
What would be the JVM limit for 64 bit linux machine??
 Given this situation, how should I deal with this constraint?

I could increase the max heap size using command line option to java, but would the JVM limit overide the Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For 32-bit Windows: it'll be <2GB
- For 32-bit BSD / Linux: <3GB
- For 32-bit MacOS X: <4GB

For 64-bit more, try this: [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/)

Commands look here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

About heap: [link](http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/05/heap-structure-in-jvm.html)